# Cross-browser alternative to CSS calc()

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, calc

The CSS `calc` method is not supported on Opera mini and IE 8. But this is such an essential method that I can't imagine that something equivalent doesn't exist for those browsers.

Is there a universally supported way I can accomplish a div that has padding, but also fills the whole screen? Or is there a way I can make this code cross-browser?

**html**

```
<div class="this-should-fill-the-whole-screen"></div>
```

**css**

```
.this-should-fill-the-whole-screen {
  padding: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wfq6xLn5/

Comment: "But this is such an essential method that I can't imagine that something equivalent doesn't exist for those browsers." If it did, we wouldn't need `calc()`.

Comment: @BoltClock There are several examples of different methods that can do the same thing. Just because calc() accomplishes what I'm trying to do doesn't mean that there is nothing else that can accomplish it.

Comment: Yes, but each of those methods is situational and uses `calc()` differently. If there were a generic solution that worked in all browsers, we wouldn't need to introduce another feature for the same purpose - we would just use that existing method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t need to “abuse” `calc` for problems for which solutions already exist – and in this case, that solution is called [`box-sizing:border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

And according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing, IE 8 and Opera Mini 8 support it.

(Both won’t play along with the `vh` unit though – but that problem you would have with `calc` as well. Whether you’ll be able to substitute `100%` for it, depends on the rest of the layout.)

Comment: Wait, why won't they play along with vh? It's worked fine so far for me.

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units, IE 8 and Opera Mini don’t have support … but I can’t say how accurate that information is (although for IE 8, I think it should be).

Comment: @Joe Morano: Mostly because there was no interest in implementing vw/vh until the early 2010s, long after IE8 was released. IE8 in particular was a CSS2.1-centric release - any CSS3 features it implemented were purely incidental.

Answer (score 3):

Here is code that you can use as a solution:

```
<style>
body, html {
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
    height:100%;
}

.this-should-fill-the-whole-screen {
    box-sizing: border-box;  
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
</style>

<div class="this-should-fill-the-whole-screen">text</div>
```